# python plot values against date

Tags: python, plot

I have a dataframe object:

```
import pandas as pd
import  matplotlib.pyplot   as  plt

data=pd.DataFrame({'date':['2013-03-04','2013-03-05','2013-03-06','2013-03-07'],'value':[1,1.1,1.2,1.3]})
```

and I would like to plot value column against date column, I've tried:

```
plt.plot(pd.to_datetime(data['date']),data['value'])
```

The x axis is not the date label I've expected. Anyone could help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just plot it like that:

```
data.plot(x='date', y='value')
```